# Probability inference of an action from a continuous outcome

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Assume person A takes an action, it could be either $a_1$ or $a_2$ with $a_1>a_2$, we cannot observe A's action but a signal $x$, with $x=a_i+\epsilon$. $\epsilon$ follows a normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma)$.
My question: how to infer the probability that person A takes action $a_1$ conditional on x, i.e. $P(a_1|x)$. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let the distribution over the $a_i$s be denoted as $P(a_i)$. Then, by [Baye's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem),
$$
P(a_1 \vert x) = \frac{f(x\vert a_1)P(a_1)}{f(x)} = \frac{f(x\vert a_1)P(a_1)}{\sum\limits_{i=1,2} f(x\vert a_i)P(a_i)} = \frac{\displaystyle \exp({-\frac{1}{2\sigma}(x-\mu-a_1)^2})P(a_1)}{\displaystyle \sum\limits_{i=1,2} \displaystyle \exp({-\frac{1}{2\sigma}(x-\mu-a_i)^2})P(a_i)}\,.
$$

Comment: I guess Baye's rule cannot be used here, because the action is chosen by person A for sure, i.e. $P(a_i)$ is either 0 or 1.

Comment: @Hucore, Yes, A has made a choice ... *but* the choice is unobservable. Therefore, to the observer for whom this choice is not directly visible (i.e. us who are interested in computing $P(a_1\vert x)$), there *is* uncertainty about what choice A has made. For us, there is a probability that $a_1$ was chosen or, alternatively, $a_2$. It is akin to me asking you to guess what choice amongst the numbers $1,2,3,4,5$, I have in mind right now; if I never tell you the choice then all you can do is guess with, some probability distribution over these numbers, what number I have actually chosen.